# Facebook API logout not logging user out completely

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing an app using Facebook's PHP and Javascript SDK..

Everything is working superbly. However, when the user logs out using the php next => link , although he is redirected, he is not logged out. What I've tried is using the Javascript SDK `getloginstatus()` and it works!

However, I would like a server side method to this as well because a user can simply disable javascript and gain access to the site. I've also tried destroying facebook session and cookies to no avail, as I suspected there might be some issues with that.

I should also note that PHP SDK is able to detect that the user is logged off  if the user has deleted all sessions and cookies.

My code is:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
//logged in
} else{

//not logged in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not have your application require js be enabled, else they are directed to a page where access cannot be gained?

Comment: That's a great idea!!is there a way to do this with PHP?

Comment: ^Also, I'm generally not comfortable using JS for security as it can be manipulated using firebug..For example a user can stop the script before window.location executes..However, this seems like s viable solution until I come up with a more reasonable one.

Comment: I think the best way to handle it via php is through an ajax call to a js script. If there's no response from the script, that could be your indicator that JS is disabled.

Comment: IDK JS just seems like it's so unsafe to rely on for authorization.

Comment: So i fixed it ...For some reason I must use the PHP SDK to login not the Javacsript SDK :) 
Hope this helps anyone with this problem..Now application is super safe (hopefully)..